# Program works fine in Debug, but not in Release

Tags: c++

I made a tic-tac-toe game which works good. Recently I decided to add a reset game feature. 
Here is the part where I take input from user

```
void playerMove() //Gets the player move and updates the box variables
{
    int boxnumber;
    while(1)      //Set's loop if the player enters a invalid input
    {
       cout << "\n Player " << player << "'s turn!(Press 0 to reset the game!): ";
       cin >> boxnumber;
       if(box[boxnumber-1] == 'X' || box[boxnumber-1] == 'O' || boxnumber > 9 || boxnumber < 0) // Checks if the input is valid or not
       {
           system("CLS");//If invalid, show error and loop back to start to get new input
           displayBoard();
           cout << "\n Invalid Input! Try again!\n";

       }else if(boxnumber == 0)
       {
           refreshGame();
           displayBoard();
       }else
       {
           box[boxnumber-1] = player;//If inputs are fine, set the box variable's and break out of loop!
           break;
       }
    }

}
```

Now, in debug mode, when I press 0, everything runs fine and the game is reset, but in release build, when I press 0, it gives me the "Invalid Input! Try again!"

Things I have tried the didnt work:
-Rebuild the entire release and debug version.
-Making a new project and copy-pasting my code. Same thing, debug works, release doesnt.

For anyone wondering, I am using code::blocks IDE. The compiler is GNU GCC.
Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: i don't think you can get box[-1]

Comment: What is `boxnumber-1` going to be in `box[boxnumber-1]` when you enter `0`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `if` statement, put the range checks in front of the value checks. That is, change

```
if(box[boxnumber-1] == 'X' || box[boxnumber-1] == 'O' || boxnumber > 9 || boxnumber < 0)
```

to

```
if(boxnumber < 0 || box number > 9 || box[boxnumber-1] == 'X' || box[boxnumber-1] == 'O')
```

That takes advantage of short-circuiting: if the input value is less than 0 or greater than 9 the value checks won't be executed. That will avoid checking things like `box[10]`, which isn't valid.

That still leaves a problem: if the user inputs 0, this code will happily check `box[-1]`, which is also out of range. To get rid of this, move the branch of the `if` statement that tests `box number == 0` in front of this part:

```
if (box number == 0)
    // whatever
else if (box[boxnumber-1] == 'X' || box[boxnumber-1] == 'O' || boxnumber > 9 || boxnumber < 0)
    // whatever else
```

Comment: This is a great fix. Never thought of this way. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: @JohnMorris11 - another suggestion: after getting the value from the user, decrement it so that the acceptable values run from 0 to 8. That will eliminate all the `-1s for the array accesses.

Answer (score 4):

You have *undefined behavior*.

In the "first" `if` you have `box[boxnumber-1]`, so when you enter `0` (as you have stated in your question), you're trying to access element with index `-1`. That's UB, as you're reading "invalid" memory.

You should check for `0` first (and for negative numbers also).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Any reasons why this works in debug but not in release?

Comment: @JohnMorris11 - because "undefined behavior" :) The generated code is different in both modes, the memory layout is different, too. So, the behavior may be/is different also.

Comment: because it may have actually still given "valid" results, by mere accident